# Setting default file upload folder (directory) in robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, automation, robotframework

We've a web application wherein it uploads attachments ( Files - JPG , PDF or any other ).
Right now to upload these files, the files need to be kept in folder  : **C:\Users\username** so that the chrome browser automatically uploads them during test automation execution.

We want to upload JPG files from a custom and generic folder so that upload is independent of the path.
Is there any way wherein we specify the chrome to choose a specific folder to upload these files  ( ex : To upload files from folder  **C:\TestData** ) independent of the user logged in ?

**So my issue is how to set the default file upload path in Chrome Browser so that all the files can be picked-up for uploading from that default directory (folder).**

**My Attempt:**

1. Launched the chrome browser in automation script.
2. In Chrome : "Setting" then searched for "download"
3. Then changed the "Downloads" location to the generic path.

After the relaunch of the chrome browser through script, still it continued to refer to   **C:\Users\username** rather than custom path specified in chrome settings.

**Screenshot attached below for reference.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Every time selenium starts a browser, it does so with a new profile - thus when you change the settings in it, they are not present the next time the automation is ran.

Here's how to set the browser's download location - the folder where any streamed is saved (I'm stressing in this, cause you seem to use upload/download interchangeably). You create a special dictionary of settings, and pass that when creating the driver:

```
${chromeOptions}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
${prefs} =    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=c:\\your\\directory
Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
Open Browser    Chrome    options=${chromeOptions}
```

Obviously, the setting you are looking for is the `download.default_directory` one.

Comment: Thanks Todor. But I wanted to set the default upload directory

Comment: Well, you did put a screenshot of the Downloads setting, plus talked about it in the question. To the topic then - there's no such thing as default upload directory. Every time you upload a file, you provide the full file path; in your case, specify "C:\\TestData\\file.txt" in the cases. If you don't, but give just a file name, I _guess_ it's taken relative to the current working directory - of the python interpreter running your script (_probably_).

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution using Open Browser Keyword to change the download directory

```
   ${prefs} =    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=C:\\Balaji
   Open Browser    https://www.google.com/    chrome    
   options=add_experimental_option("prefs",${prefs})
   Maximize Browser Window
   Set Browser Implicit Wait    20
```